# I need to merge 2 Arrays together, with probably same data

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have to merge 2 Arrays like these:

Array1 (Data from API):

```
{ '0':
   { userid: 'kdkds',
     name: 'Stephan,
     email:  'stephan@aaa.com' ,
     tag: '2015-04-02',
     schicht_id: 'pikett',
     schicht_name: 'Pikett',
     beschreibung: null,
     administrativ: '0' },
  '1':
   { userid: 'kdkds',
     name: 'Stephan',
     email:  'stephan@aaa.com' ,
     tag: '2015-04-03',
     schicht_id: 'pikett',
     schicht_name: 'Pikett',
     beschreibung: null,
     administrativ: '0' } };
```

Array2(Data from DB):

```
{ '0':
   { userid: 'kdkds',
     del: 'true',
     art: 'Pikett' ,
     datum: '2015-04-02'},
  '1':
   { userid: 'kdkds',
     del: 'false',
     art: 'Pikett',
     datum: '2015-04-03'}

};
```

What I need at the end is the first array with the additional data from the second array with the matching userid and date:

```
{ '0':
       { userid: 'kdkds',
         name: 'Stephan,
         email:  'stephan@aaa.com' ,
         tag: '2015-04-02',
         schicht_id: 'pikett',
         schicht_name: 'Pikett',
         beschreibung: null,
         administrativ: '0',
         del: 'true'},
      '1':
       { userid: 'kdkds',
         name: 'Stephan',
         email:  'stephan@aaa.com' ,
         tag: '2015-04-03',
         schicht_id: 'pikett',
         schicht_name: 'Pikett',
         beschreibung: null,
         administrativ: '0',
         del: 'false' } };
```

If there is a entry in the second array which is not in the second array, it also have to be in the final array.

I use nodejs, so what is the easiest way?

Comment: Just a note: there are no arrays here, just objects with keys.

Comment: those are **objects** not **array**. Show us what have you tried ?

Comment: Besides them not actually being arrays. Are Array1 and Array2 always the same length?

Comment: Loop through the first object. For each record in that first, check if the second has a record where the userid is the same and the tag from record 1 is the same as record2. Extend the first record with the extra parameters from the second for the matching ones..

Comment: Assuming you are saving data from API object in your DB object and allways API object will be the one containing extra info (maybe my assumption is wrong). The most efficient way is iterate only over API object and insert in DB object the new data.

Comment: What does this have to do with node.js?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment my solution is:

```
function merge () {
        var dst = {}
            ,src
            ,p
            ,args = [].splice.call(arguments, 0)
        ;

        while (args.length > 0) {
            src = args.splice(0, 1)[0];
            if (toString.call(src) == '[object Object]') {
                for (p in src) {
                    if (src.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                        if (toString.call(src[p]) == '[object Object]') {
                            dst[p] = merge(dst[p] || {}, src[p]);
                        } else {
                            dst[p] = src[p];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return dst;
    }
```

But I have to do some tests

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy. Just loop the objects through.

```
var result = Array1
for(var i in Array2){
  if(result[i]){
    for(var p in Array2[i]){
      result[i][p] = Array2[i][p]
    }
  }
  else {result[i] = Array2[i]}
}
```

Warning: The Array1 gets modified and has references to Array2.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you don't want to merge arrays but objects, you might want to do something like this:

```
var mergeFunction = function(a1, a2) { 
    // Settings
    var propertyToCompareArray1 = ['userid', 'tag'];
    var propertyToCompareArray2 = ['userid', 'datum'];

    for(var i = 0; i<Object.keys(a2).length;i++) 
    { 
      var itemA2 = Object.keys(a2)[i];
      for(var j = 0; j<Object.keys(a2[itemA2]).length;j++) {
        var currentProp = Object.keys(a2[itemA2])[j];
        var shouldSkip = false;
        for(var l=0;l<propertyToCompareArray2.length;l++) {
           if(currentProp === propertyToCompareArray2[l])
             shouldSkip = true;
         }

          if(shouldSkip)
              continue;

         for(var k=0; k<Object.keys(a1).length; k++) {
             var doesMatch = true;
            for(var l=0;l<propertyToCompareArray1.length;l++) {
                if(a1[Object.keys(a1)[k]][propertyToCompareArray1[l]] === a2[itemA2][propertyToCompareArray2[l]])
                {
                    doesMatch = false;
                }
            }
             if(doesMatch)
             {
                 a1[itemA2][currentProp] = a2[itemA2][currentProp];
                 continue;
             }
         }
      }
    }
    return a1;
};
```

Then run : `var res = mergeFunction(obj1, obj2);`

The result would be:

```
{
   '0': 
   {
      administrativ: "0",
      art: "Pikett",
      beschreibung: null,
      datum: "2015-04-02",
      del: "true",
      email: "stephan@aaa.com",
      name: "Stephan",
      schicht_id: "pikett",
      schicht_name: "Pikett",
      tag: "2015-04-02",
      userid: "kdkds"
   },
   '1':
   {
      administrativ: "0",
      art: "Pikett",
      beschreibung: null,
      datum: "2015-04-03",
      del: "false",
      email: "stephan@aaa.com",
      name: "Stephan",
      schicht_id: "pikett",
      schicht_name: "Pikett",
      tag: "2015-04-03",
      userid: "kdkds"
 }
```

**Edit:**

This code works if you use objects described in your question, and if you work with real arrays like this:

```
var obj1 = [ 
{ 
   userid: 'kdkds',
   name: 'Stephan',
   email:  'stephan@aaa.com' ,
   tag: '2015-04-02',
   schicht_id: 'pikett',
   schicht_name: 'Pikett',
   beschreibung: null,
   administrativ: '0'
 },
 {
   userid: 'kdkds',
   name: 'Stephan',
   email:  'stephan@aaa.com' ,
   tag: '2015-04-03',
   schicht_id: 'pikett',
   schicht_name: 'Pikett',
   beschreibung: null,
   administrativ: '0'
 }
];
```

and:

```
var obj2= [
   { 
     userid: 'kdkds',
     del: 'true',
     art: 'Pikett' ,
     datum: '2015-04-02'
   },
   {
     userid: 'kdkds',
     del: 'false',
     art: 'Pikett',
     datum: '2015-04-03'
}
];
```

**EDIT 2:**

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/cef61yo7/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using underscore easily, but if you want pure javascript implementation, you can try other's solution. This is just short solution.

If the keys of your object is exactly like the index of an array you can convert it to array like so:

```
obj1.length = _.size(obj1);

var newArr = [];

newArr = Array.prototype.map.call(obj1, function(el, index, arr){
    return _.extend(el, obj2[index])
});
```

The new array will contain your merged result as array. If there are common property in the merging objects, the `_.merge` will override the first with the second one. But as I said, this is solution using underscore.

Documentation for 
[underscore extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) 
 [underscore size](http://underscorejs.org/#size)

**EDIT 1**
This works only if the keys of your object corresponds to array's index. Like in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6:

```
Array1 . forEach((elt, idx) => Object.assign(elt, Array2[idx]));
```

This modifies Array1. To create a new array:

```
Array1. map((elt, idx) => Object.assign({}, elt, Array2[idx]));
```

This assumes the inputs are actual arrays.

You can run this using `babel-node`. With `node --harmony` you'll need to provide a shim for `Object.assign.`

Answer (score 0):

An easy and reusable way to achieve this:

```
function merge(a1, a2, doMerge) { 
    for(var item1 in a1) 
    { 
       for(var item2 in a2){
          if(doMerge(item1, item2)){
              for(var prop in item2){
                item1[prop] = item2[prop];   
              }
          };
       }
    }
    return a1;
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var res = merge(obj1, obj2, function(item1, item2){
    return item1.userid === item2.userid && item1.tag === item2.datum;
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cef61yo7/5/